# IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I'm SVM (RBF kernel) to learn my data and try to find optimal gamma and C, my code is this:

```
from sklearn import svm

C = np.array([1, 10, 100, 1000])
gamma = np.array([1e-3, 1e-4])

avg_rbf_f1 = []

for a in C:
    for b in gamma:
        rbf_model = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf',C=a, gamma=b)
        rbf_scores = cross_val_score(rbf_model, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='f1_macro')
        avg_rbf_f1.append(np.mean(rbf_scores))

best_gamma = gamma[np.argmax(avg_rbf_f1)]
best_C = C[np.argmax(avg_rbf_f1)]

print('The gamma with the highest accuracy is {}'.format(best_gamma))
print('The C with the highest accuracy is {}'.format(best_C))
```

and I have the title as the error. I know it may because my gamma has only size 2. but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Which line throwing the error?

Comment: best_gamma = gamma[np.argmax(avg_rbf_f1)]   this one, best_C works

Comment: `best_C` "works" by accident. Quotes as you don't get the right answer, it just stays within bounds and therefore not produce an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of the answer let's have your code in a form that others can reproduce the issue:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

np.random.seed(42)
X = np.random.rand(2000, 2)
y = np.random.randint(0,2,2000)

C = np.array([1, 10, 100, 1000])
gamma = np.array([1e-3, 1e-4])

avg_rbf_f1 = []

for a in C:
    for b in gamma:
        rbf_model = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf',C=a, gamma=b)
        rbf_scores = cross_val_score(rbf_model, X, y, cv=10, scoring='f1_macro')
        avg_rbf_f1.append(np.mean(rbf_scores))

best_gamma = gamma[np.argmax(avg_rbf_f1)]
best_C = C[np.argmax(avg_rbf_f1)]

print('The gamma with the highest accuracy is {}'.format(best_gamma))
print('The C with the highest accuracy is {}'.format(best_C))
```

And the error itself:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-84d1adf5e2d9> in <module>()
     17         avg_rbf_f1.append(np.mean(rbf_scores))
     18 
---> 19 best_gamma = gamma[np.argmax(avg_rbf_f1)]
     20 best_C = C[np.argmax(avg_rbf_f1)]
     21 

IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Hyperparameter `gamma` has 2 possible values, while `avg_rbf_f1` is a list of 8. In the way you have currently implemented the grid search, there's no way you can get back your best params. Here's how you can modify your code so that it works:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

np.random.rand(42)
X = np.random.rand(2000, 2)
y = np.random.randint(0,2,2000)

C = np.array([1, 10, 100, 1000])
gamma = np.array([1e-3, 1e-4])

avg_rbf_f1 = []
search = []

for a in C:
    for b in gamma:
        search.append((a,b))
        rbf_model = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf',C=a, gamma=b)
        rbf_scores = cross_val_score(rbf_model, X, y, cv=10, scoring='f1_macro')
        avg_rbf_f1.append(np.mean(rbf_scores))

best_C, best_gamma = search[np.argmax(avg_rbf_f1)]

print('The gamma with the highest accuracy is {}'.format(best_gamma))
print('The C with the highest accuracy is {}'.format(best_C))
```

It's far from optimal. I simply added `search` list that collects combination of C and gamma.

What would be optimal then? Use [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV). Takes a lot of coding off your back.

Comment: @Poppy You're welcome! Please accept my answer so that other people know it is resolved.